# Interface members cannot have a definition

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Why I'm unable to add default implementation of this interface?

I have C# 8 / .NET Core 3.0 (as seen in Main)

But for some reason it yells:

> 'ITest.Test()': interface members cannot have a definition

```
interface ITest
{
    // Interface members cannot have a definition
    void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Interface");
    }
}

public class Test : ITest
{
    void ITest.Test()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // this works properly
        var arr = "test".ToCharArray();

        Console.WriteLine(arr[1..2]);
        Console.WriteLine(arr[..2]);
        Console.WriteLine(arr[..^1]);
        Console.WriteLine(arr[^1..]);
    }
}
```

Comment: An interface is a contract and should only contains the signature of the methods in it.

Comment: Interface members can not have definition - that is true for all version of C#. `"test".ToCharArray();` works because `"test"` is string. It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, please read [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/default-interface-methods.md).

Comment: I don't think default interface implementation made it into the recent VS2019/C#8 preview.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Take a look at the code below ``"test".ToCharArray();``

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya this is a question about C# 8 which *does* have default interface methods

Comment: @Cid not quite - the question is about C# 8 which *does* have default interface methods. Java has them since Java 8. They *don't* break contracts either, they are a way to make interface versioning easier and implement traits

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is it live?

Comment: @Cid define live - experimental compilers have been available since April. The duplicate has the answers. This question is probably the most common in the c#-8.0 tag after the C# 8 and .NET Core announcements in Microsoft Connect last week

Comment: By live I mean provided by the official compiler

Comment: @Cid No, it is only a planned feature and is not in the C# 8.0 preview build. See my answer below for the source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default interface methods feature is [not available yet, even in the C# 8.0 preview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/12/05/take-c-8-0-for-a-spin/) (confirmed by a Microsoft rep in response to the "Rand.Random" commenter asking about this feature not being in the preview).

If you want to provide an implementation, I would recommend using inheritance and virtual methods.

```
public class TestBase
{
    public virtual void TestMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestBase");
    }
}

public class Test : TestBase
{
    public override void TestMethod()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testBase = new TestBase();
        testBase.TestMethod(); // Prints "TestBase"

        var test = new Test();
        test.TestMethod(); // Throws NotImplementedException
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because this feature is not available yet. Per [dymanoid's link](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/default-interface-methods.md), this feature is in the prototype stage. It's not mentioned in the [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/12/05/take-c-8-0-for-a-spin/) for the C# 8.0 beta.